# Missing Apple build options

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

What am I missing to find the other options in my build choices?

I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate update 4, Tools for Apache Cordova CTP 3.0 installed, but I could not find Apple device or emulator options.

I have my Mac remote debugger agent up and running, so please, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have found it. I should view the **Solution Platforms** drop down list first from Add/Remove more buttons and then select iOS.